# class "jqgrid-new-row" will be added by addRow but never removed

Tags: jqgrid, row, addition

I've read a thread recently about a bug into the jqgrid addrow function :
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/class-jqgrid-new-row-will-be-added-by-addrow-but-never-removed/

Could you please send me the code to add to the grid.inlinedit.js ? I'm a newbie in Jqgrid and I don't know how to remove a class to the row.

Oleg, i will really appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Are you asking help from someone who made a post on another site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug which I reported [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/class-jqgrid-new-row-will-be-added-by-addrow-but-never-removed/#p28527) is already fixed in the main code of jqGrid on [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid). You can see the current code of `grid.inlinedit.js` [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js) and download [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/archive/master.zip).

By the way I suggested Tony (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/releases/jqgrid-4-4-4/#p28591)) to publish the current version of jqGrid from github as new release (4.4.5) of jqGrid. He answered (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/releases/jqgrid-4-4-4/#p28604)) that he plan to do this this week. So probably you could just wait 1-2 days and download the new fixed version of jqGrid from [the standard download place](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).

Comment: @user2137398: jqGrid 4.4.5 can be downloaded now. See [the standard download place](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).